Why can my command embedded in a script only able to be executed when typed in the terminal?
I wrote a script to get sequences corresponding to some id's.
    # Process each genome ID in array
    for id in "${genome_ids[@]}"; do
        echo "Processing genome ID: $id"
        # Construct the command
        command="p3-genome-fasta --protein $id"
        
        # Execute the command
        $command 


Example output:
Processing genome ID: 1000289.10
p3-genome-fasta --protein 1000289.10
. at /usr/share/bvbrc-cli/deployment/plbin/p3-genome-fasta.pl line 47.
It says there's an error, but when I copy and paste the command printed to the screen, it works?
Related code from p3-genome-fasta.pl
# Get the genome ID.
my ($genomeID) = @ARGV;
if (! $genomeID) {
    die "No genome ID specified.";
} elsif (! ($genomeID =~ /^\d+\.\d+$/)) {
    die "Invalid genome ID $genomeID.";
}


@user68186 I tried eval $command but I got the same output as before. I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Processing genome ID: 1000289.10
p3-genome-fasta --protein 1000289.10
. at /usr/share/bvbrc-cli/deployment/plbin/p3-genome-fasta.pl line 47.

Please edit your question and add the additional information you have put in comments inside your question. Comments are our channel to ask you for clarifications. You should update your question.

Look at lines 40 through 50 of /usr/share/bvbrc-cli/deployment/plbin/p3-genome-fasta.pl. It's a Perl script and is generally human readable. Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables!

Just an update for everyone. I managed to solve it. I had created the text file in windows and had CRLF characters. Managed to fix it by running dos2unix command.
